# In SQL, accept a user prompt via keyboard, then add a wildcard to pull everything like it

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I can't seem to get this to work. I need to type in a word or letter, and return everything that contains that letter or word at the beginning of it's entry. My code:

```
ACCEPT v_name PROMPT 'Enter the name or letter: '

select *
from customer c
where UPPER(c.name) LIKE UPPER('%'||$$v_name||'%');
```

I am using sql developer and sql plus.

Comment: someone posted a comment and deleted it and it solved my issue. thanks, guy.

Comment: I just undeleted the answer after revising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `&v_name` by itself, without a prompt, the tool will automatically prompt you. You only need ACCEPT and PROMPT if you want to customize the message to the user.

Put the variable inside the quotes when using its value in a string, prefixed by `&`. It is a substitution var, so it doesn't need concatenation. Substitution vars are just interpolated variables implemented in the query tool, prior to the SQL being parsed, which explains why they work inside quotes.

```
select * from customer c where UPPER(c.name) LIKE UPPER('%&v_name%');
```

Or customizing the prompt, using accept. Note no `&` on the v_name in the ACCEPT command, only in the substitution:

```
ACCEPT v_name PROMPT 'Enter the name or letter: '

select * from customer c where UPPER(c.name) LIKE UPPER('%&v_name%');
```